# Issues with fgets

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while, fgets

Let fp1 point to a file called file1, fp2 point to a file called file2. file1 and file2 are exactly same. And no file open errors.

But function test_fgets prints out different strings. The line printf("%s", lptr1) prints out NULL, but printf("%s", lptr2) prints out the last line of file2.

Since file1 and file2 are exactly the same, why print different outputs?

Besides, when I tried to change printf("%s", lptr1) to printf("%s\n", lptr1), it gave me a segmentation fault(core dump) error. Why is it? How does a newline character affect here?

```
...
#define MAXLINE 100
char line1[MAXLINE];
char line2[MAXLINE];

...
void test_fgets(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2){

   char *lptr1;
   char *lptr2;

   while( (lptr1 = fgets(line1, MAXLINE, fp1)) && (lptr2 = fgets(line2, MAXLINE, fp2)))
          ;

   printf("%s", lptr1);
   printf("%s", lptr2); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop runs until fgets fails, indicated by a nullptr. Oh, the second fgets is not executed since it's a && condition, so lptr2 still holds its last line.

Comment: But (lptr2 = fgets(line2, MAXLINE, fp2)) is bracketed. It should have higher precedence than &&. So the assignments of lptr1 and lptr2 happen first, then && is performed.

Comment: rtfm. The left operand of && is evaluated; if it's false, the right one is not. Quite essential for `if(p && *p==1)`.

Comment: It's called lazy evaluation.  Once the truth or falsehood of an expression is determined it won't evaluate the rest.

Comment: @StephenRasku Well, it's less general: It's not an arbitrary "Once the truth or falsehood of an expression is determined", but it's strictly left first. I bet you in `if(f() && 0)`f() is executed. And it only applies to the && and || operators, not e.g. to | and &. So in `if(0 & f()) `f() will always be executed.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, Correct, I was assuming left-to-right evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
while( (lptr1 = fgets(line1, MAXLINE, fp1)) && (lptr2 = fgets(line2, MAXLINE, fp2)));
```

if the first expression

```
(lptr1 = fgets(line1, MAXLINE, fp1))
```

is equal to `false` then the second expression

```
(lptr2 = fgets(line2, MAXLINE, fp2))
```

is not evaluated. So the second printf prints the previous content of `line2` because `lptr2` was not changed. It is only `lptr1` that was changed to NULL.

To get the desired result you should change the while loop to a do..while loop. For example

```
   do
   {
      lptr1 = fgets(line1, MAXLINE, fp1);
      lptr2 = fgets(line2, MAXLINE, fp2)'
   } while( lptr1 && lptr2 );
```

Comment: But (lptr2 = fgets(line2, MAXLINE, fp2)) is bracketed. It should have higher precedence than &&. So the assignments of lptr1 and lptr2 happen first, then && is performed

Comment: @user3506287  it is no matter that expression are enclosed in parentheses. The second operand of operator && is not evaluated if the first operand is equal to false. The parsing of the condition is differen than you think.